# Switching Eclipse Neon to use a more recent version of SWT

Tags: eclipse, swt

I am running Eclipse Neon on openSUSE Linux. As luck would have it, some GTK 3 fixes arrived too late to be added to this release, so I need a more recent version of SWT.

However, just adding the update site and trying to update SWT does not work. Here's what I did:

1. Added the 4.7 stream update site to Eclipse: http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.7-I-builds/
2. Opened the Install dialog and selected `Eclipse Platform 4.7.0.I20160719-0800`
3. Pressed `Next`

At this point the progress bar indicated that it 'Cannot perform operation. Computing alternate solutions, may take a while'.

After that I'm presented with a screenshot like the one below, which suggests that I need to uninstall parts of my IDE - not sure how much it will uninstall since 'Eclipse  IDE for Java Developers' brings in a large number of features.

[image: Update Dialog]

How can I update my Eclipse Neon instance to a newer version of SWT?

Comment: Eclipse 4.7 is still in the very early stages of development, it hasn't even reached Milestone 1 yet.

Comment: @greg-449 - note that this is about SWT, not about the whole Eclipse platform. I just did not find a more fine-grained way to try and upgrade SWT.

Answer (score 0):

As of now, you cannot update from one major version of Eclipse to another, e.g. 4.6 to 4.7. Only updates to minor versions, e.g.4.6.1, are supported. You would need to 'reinstall' the new version to get the fixes. As [Greg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2670892/greg-449) mentioned, in your case, this may also include unstable new features.

See this wiki page for more details https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_upgrade_Eclipse_IDE%3F

Comment: Note that this is about SWT, not about the whole Eclipse platform. I just did not find a more fine-grained way to try and upgrade SWT.

Comment: SWT is part of Eclipse's platform feature and cannot be updated on its own. If SWT was provided in a separate feature, it would probably be easy to update.